# Starting GFSH - Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler'

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, gemfire

I am trying to connect GFSH (gemfire) to our existing locator.  The locator is running on 10334 and it has a gemfire server connected to it.  I am able to verify this via a unit test in Spring Boot.  When I try to connect GFSH to this locator I always get the following message.

> Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler'

The command I am using is `gfsh connect`  I also tried it explicitly with localhost and port.

```
 ack-severe-alert-threshold=0
ack-wait-threshold=15
archive-disk-space-limit=0
archive-file-size-limit=0
async-distribution-timeout=0
async-max-queue-size=8
async-queue-timeout=60000
bind-address=
cache-xml-file=cache.xml
cluster-configuration-dir=.
cluster-ssl-ciphers=any
cluster-ssl-enabled=false
cluster-ssl-keystore=
cluster-ssl-keystore-password=
cluster-ssl-keystore-type=
cluster-ssl-protocols=any
cluster-ssl-require-authentication=true
cluster-ssl-truststore=
cluster-ssl-truststore-password=
conflate-events=server
conserve-sockets=true
delta-propagation=true
deploy-working-dir=.
disable-auto-reconnect=false
disable-tcp=false
distributed-system-id=-1
durable-client-id=
durable-client-timeout=300
enable-cluster-configuration=true
enable-network-partition-detection=false
enable-time-statistics=false
enforce-unique-host=false
gateway-ssl-ciphers=any
gateway-ssl-enabled=false
gateway-ssl-keystore=
gateway-ssl-keystore-password=
gateway-ssl-keystore-type=
gateway-ssl-protocols=any
gateway-ssl-require-authentication=true
gateway-ssl-truststore=
gateway-ssl-truststore-password=
groups=
http-service-bind-address=
http-service-port=7070
http-service-ssl-ciphers=any
http-service-ssl-enabled=false
http-service-ssl-keystore=
http-service-ssl-keystore-password=
http-service-ssl-keystore-type=
http-service-ssl-protocols=any
http-service-ssl-require-authentication=false
http-service-ssl-truststore=
http-service-ssl-truststore-password=
jmx-manager=false
jmx-manager-access-file=
jmx-manager-bind-address=
jmx-manager-hostname-for-clients=
jmx-manager-http-port=7070
jmx-manager-password-file=
jmx-manager-port=1099
jmx-manager-ssl=false
jmx-manager-ssl-ciphers=any
jmx-manager-ssl-enabled=false
jmx-manager-ssl-keystore=
jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-password=
jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-type=
jmx-manager-ssl-protocols=any
jmx-manager-ssl-require-authentication=true
jmx-manager-ssl-truststore=
jmx-manager-ssl-truststore-password=
jmx-manager-start=false
jmx-manager-update-rate=2000
license-application-cache=
license-data-management=
license-server-timeout=10000
license-working-dir=
load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false
locator-wait-time=0
locators=
log-disk-space-limit=0
log-file=
log-file-size-limit=0
log-level=config
max-num-reconnect-tries=3
max-wait-time-reconnect=60000
mcast-address=239.192.81.1
mcast-flow-control=1048576, 0.25, 5000
mcast-port=10334
mcast-recv-buffer-size=1048576
mcast-send-buffer-size=65535
mcast-ttl=32
member-timeout=5000
membership-port-range=1024-65535
memcached-bind-address=
memcached-port=0
memcached-protocol=ASCII
name=
redundancy-zone=
remote-locators=
remove-unresponsive-client=false
roles=
security-=
security-client-accessor=
security-client-accessor-pp=
security-client-auth-init=
security-client-authenticator=
security-client-dhalgo=
security-log-file=
security-log-level=config
security-peer-auth-init=
security-peer-authenticator=
security-peer-verifymember-timeout=1000
server-bind-address=
server-ssl-ciphers=any
server-ssl-enabled=false
server-ssl-keystore=
server-ssl-keystore-password=
server-ssl-keystore-type=
server-ssl-protocols=any
server-ssl-require-authentication=true
server-ssl-truststore=
server-ssl-truststore-password=
socket-buffer-size=32768
socket-lease-time=60000
start-dev-rest-api=false
start-locator=
statistic-archive-file=
statistic-sample-rate=1000
statistic-sampling-enabled=true
tcp-port=0
udp-fragment-size=60000
udp-recv-buffer-size=1048576
udp-send-buffer-size=65535
use-cluster-configuration=true
user-command-packages=
```

I don't get any other errors when I try to start the server.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind sharing more information about your setup? maybe share your locator's gemfire.properties? On gfsh side, you can run `export JAVA_ARGS=-Dgfsh.log-level=config` before you launch gfsh, to get a log of gfsh in your launch directory. Share the content there to give us more clue please.

Comment: I added gemfire.properties.  I didn't change much bc my locator is on localhost:10334 and cache server on localhost:40404 which are the default locations I thought.  I added logging as suggested but no more details were written to stdout.  I verified the logging was set correctly.

Comment: there should be a seperate log file generated. do you see any file extra in the directory where you launch gfsh?